# Getting a runtime error while pushing app for testflight in XCode

Tags: flutter, xcode, firebase, dart

I am trying to push my flutter app to testflight and I am getting this error in Xcode during runtime:

> 'AssetManifest' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/services/asset_manifest.dart' and 'package:google_fonts/src/asset_manifest.dart'

I have updated the google_fonts package to the latest (google_fonts: ^5.1.0 at the time of uploading this problem) but it still shows this error. It runs fine on android but doesn't allow on xcode while running for iOS. I also tried "pod update" but still the issue exists.

Comment: Are you able to run your app on iOS?

Comment: No, I tried running it too but it shows the same error

Comment: try to repair the cache with a command: `flutter pub cache repair`

Comment: What error do you get from `flutter run`?

Comment: Thank you @Volodymyr , I tried "flutter pub cache repair" and it solved my issue. Thank you so much once again!

Comment: @SultanShah glad to hear that. You can upvote the comment which helped you)